# Python Need to split huge excel into little excels. Coding not working

Tags: python, excel

I have a big excel and I need to split it into little ones (I'm using python). It should take every 300 lines of the big excel and write them into the first 300 lines of the little excels (each little excel should have 300 lines or less, the last one). The big excel is just an excel with element in the first column (A:A) and about 8.000 rows (cells contain emails).

The code is the following:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlsxwriter


wb = open_workbook('BBDD_POLAROID_TOTAL.xlsx')
excel_num = 0
print('ARCHIVO: ' + str(excel_num))
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('BBDD' + str(excel_num) + '.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for s in wb.sheets():
    number_of_rows = s.nrows
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        if row % 300 == 0:
            print('close: ' + str(excel_num))
            workbook.close()
            excel_num += 1
            print('ARCHIVO: ' + str(excel_num))
            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('BBDD' + str(excel_num) + '.xlsx')
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
            print('all good: ' + str(excel_num))
        print(str(row) + s.cell(row, 0).value)
        worksheet.write(row, 0, s.cell(row, 0).value)
```

I can't see why this code is not working. It actually crate all the excels but only writes on the second one (first one just open and close).

Thanks for the help !

Comment: This has been really confusing me too until now, I think I found the problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it yet. The problem is the line `if row % 300 == 0:` is `True` for the first row, (`row == 0`, `0 % 300 == 0` is `True`), so it closes the workbook, and repeats the loop starting at row `1`. I'll update if I can figure something out, unless you can fix it.

Comment: I make a code that works. Not pretty, but it makes the trick. Thanks for your help ! If you get how ti fix the code I'll be glad, I still have the doubt.

Comment: Sure, I can post a link to my "fix", or as an answer here, but it may not be any better than the answer you provided below. Regardless, as long as you have it fixed, may be enough for your needs.

Comment: I basically added a second `if` condition: `if row % 300 == 0:
            if row == 0:
                print(str(row) + s.cell(row, 0).value);
                worksheet.write(row%300, 0, s.cell(row, 0).value);
            else:
                print('close: ' + str(excel_num))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible workaround for the reason I mentioned in the comment:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlsxwriter


wb = open_workbook('BBDD_POLAROID_TOTAL.xlsx')
excel_num = 0
print('ARCHIVO: ' + str(excel_num))
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('BBDD' + str(excel_num) + '.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for s in wb.sheets():
    number_of_rows = s.nrows
    for row in range(0, number_of_rows):
        if row % 300 == 0:
            if row == 0:
                print(str(row) + s.cell(row, 0).value)
                worksheet.write(row%300, 0, s.cell(row, 0).value)
            else:
                print('close: ' + str(excel_num))
                workbook.close()
                excel_num += 1
                print('ARCHIVO: ' + str(excel_num))
                workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('BBDD' + str(excel_num) + '.xlsx')
                worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
                print('all good: ' + str(excel_num))
        print(str(row) + ' ' + s.cell(row, 0).value)
        worksheet.write(row%300, 0, s.cell(row, 0).value)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Also, in the original code, each file was not starting again at row `0`, instead starting at the next row, so each split file was not smaller than the original and filled with empty rows. Here, using ` worksheet.write(row%300..`etc, each little excel will 300 lines or less

Answer (score 1):

Well, this code makes what I wanted. But I still don't get why the other code was wrong. If someone have the answer, I'll be glad.

PD: the print is just to see how the files are been written.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlsxwriter


wb = open_workbook('BBDD_POLAROID_TOTAL.xlsx')
archivo = [[]]
excel_num = 0

for s in wb.sheets():
    number_of_rows = s.nrows
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        print(str(excel_num) + ' ' + str(row) + ' ' + s.cell(row, 0).value)
        archivo[excel_num].append(s.cell(row, 0).value)
        if row % 300 == 0 and row != 0:
            archivo.append([])
            excel_num += 1

for name in range(len(archivo)):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('BBDD' + str(name) + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for mail_index in range(len(archivo[name])):
        print(str(name) + ' ' + str(mail_index) + ' ' + archivo[name][mail_index])
        worksheet.write(mail_index, 0, archivo[name][mail_index])
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: Did you read my comment? I mentioned the reason why it doesn't work in my comment

Comment: I just finished testing a similar solution that may not be better than what you have here. But I think any solution will need to handle the condition of the first row, row zero, is `True` for the `if row % 300 == 0:`.

Comment: Yep. I read the comment and you are probably right. I think the error may be there.

Comment: Ok, whichever solution makes sense to you as a "solution" and works for your needs. The main goal is that it works. Glad to see you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
**I have something better for columns also**



    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jul 27 17:01:57 2020

@author: Vishal Yadav
"""

from xlrd import open_workbook
import xlsxwriter

file_path='E:\project\file_to_be_splitted.xls'
output_path='E:\project\splitter_output'
row_split_count=990

wb = open_workbook(file_path)
excel_num = 0
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_path+'\\'+str(excel_num) + '.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for s in wb.sheets():
    number_of_rows = s.nrows
    number_of_cols = s.ncols
    print(number_of_rows)
    print(number_of_cols)
    for row in range(0, number_of_rows):
        for col in range(0, number_of_cols):
            if(row % row_split_count == 0 and row!=0 and row<=row_split_count):
                worksheet.write(row_split_count, col, s.cell(row, col).value)
                if(col == number_of_cols-1):
                    workbook.close()
                    excel_num=excel_num+1
                    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_path+'\\'+str(excel_num) + '.xlsx')
                    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
            elif(row % row_split_count == 0 and row!=0 and row>row_split_count):
                worksheet.write(row_split_count-1, col, s.cell(row, col).value)
                if(col == number_of_cols-1):
                    workbook.close()
                    excel_num=excel_num+1
                    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_path+'\\'+str(excel_num) + '.xlsx')
                    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
            elif(row<row_split_count):
                worksheet.write(row % row_split_count, col, s.cell(row, col).value)
            else:
                worksheet.write((row % row_split_count)-1, col, s.cell(row, col).value)
    workbook.close()
```